# How to configure a pull request quorum making an organizational constraint?

Tags: git, organization

Consider the following situation.

Alice and Anna, Bob and Bart, and finally Eve and Evelyn work on same Git project in three different organizations.

How can they configure a quorum for pull requests, which requires *at least 2 votes but from two different organizations*?

Example:

- Votes from Alice and Anna - no quorum achieved possible as both votes come from the same organization;
- Votes from Alice and Bob - quorum has been achieved because team members from two different organizations have voted.

Comment: Guess you mean github or gitlab, not git (?)

Comment: Did you try to create a test setup, e.g. with bitbucket and github? If true, could you share your findings? Did you find any blogs that tried to achieve the same?

Comment: @030 nopes - maybe close this question or migrate to stack overlow.

Comment: Seems like a job for a custom bot. The identities and weights of votes (veto power, seniority, etc) could be coded into it.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like the idea, based on what I know while working with Gitlab, Bitbucket and Github I do not believe that it is currently possible as I cannot remember that such integrations were available.

Also Googling: `github bitbucket pull request approvals integrated` did not return any positive results.

I think that the users should always be part of the same organization in order to approve Pull Requests. However, when I think about github I can remember that I was able to invite people as a collaborator even when they were not part or part of any organization.

In conclusion, I think that it is possible, but only in a certain git-server providers like GitHub. My suggestion is to try it and otherwise report an issue in the associate Github project.